# COMO AGREGAR NUEVA FUNCIONALIDAD AL LOGIN DE LARAVEL JETSTREAM

Tags: php, laravel, login, laravel-jetstream

Buen dia, me gusta usar laravel jetstream, estoy aprendiendo. Me gustaría saber como podría hacer para agregar funcionalidades al login, por ejemplo que se pueda detectar si la contraseña con la que ingresa es la contraseña por defecto, de ser así que sea redirigido a la pestaña de cambio de contraseña y no permita ingresar al sistema como tal hasta que realice su cambio de contraseña, ya consulte la documentación, pero la verdad no entendí muy bien donde se puede personalizar. Cualquier ayuda muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Luis, tu pregunta es demasiado abarcativa, te sugiero que la edites, y la enfoques en un solo tema, además, es necesario que nos muestres que has intentado para poder trabajar sobre tu código, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.